# Is there a way to distinguish dual-mono and stereo in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have an audio decoder library and I am writing a Gstreamer plugin for it.

I am setting the plugin's source cap as

```
caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("audio/x-raw",
                "format",G_TYPE_STRING,"S16LE",
                "layout", G_TYPE_STRING,"interleaved",
                "rate", G_TYPE_INT, sample_freq,
                "channels", G_TYPE_INT, channels,
                NULL);
```

My question is, how do I inform Gstreamer framework that whether the audio is stereo or dual-mono as in both the cases, channels will be 2?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen elements to use

```
channel-mode=dual
```

as an extra cap flag.

I have seen `mono, stereo, dual, joint` as options. Of course it depends on the downstream elements to understand these fields and act accordingly.

This is a private good-will agreement. It is not any official define in any way. The format doesn't declare this in any way (as far as I know).

The correct way would be to have two mono tracks.

Comment: You mean two source pads to decoder when "dual-mono" stream is found?

Comment: I would suggest so yes. I don't know your use case but two pads make it clear there are multiple independent things.